# How can I avoid my program to keep running when I close my main frame?

Tags: python-3.x, button, wxpython, frame

I am currently learning wxPython library on my own. I got the idea to create a GUI with one main frame which can open a child one.

I know I can do it by compiling both frame into the same code, but for my project, I need to have them separated.

I succeeded in managing the opening of the child frame and its closing, but unfortunately, it creates a new problem in my parent frame.

Here are my codes :

wx_Practicing.py

```
import wx
import time
import wx_Practicing_child
import threading
import os
import sys

"""Class which defines my main frame."""

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test", wx.DefaultPosition,
        (1000,850), wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, wx.FrameNameStr)

        # Click counter
        self.click = 0

        # Init of the opening variable which is set to 1 when a child frame is opened
        self.OpenButtonFlag = 0

        # Init of the frame child invoked by the parent frame
        self.child = wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child()
        self.child.label = "child"

        # Sizers
        sizer_hori = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_verti = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Init of the panel

        test_panel = PanelMainWindow(self)
        test_panel.SetSizer(sizer_verti)

        # Buttons declaration
        # Button to quit the main frame
        btn_quit = wx.Button(test_panel, label ="Quit")
        btn_quit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        sizer_verti.Add(btn_quit)

        # Button counting number of time you trigger it

        btn_counter = wx.Button(test_panel, label="Click counter")
        sizer_verti.Add(btn_counter)
        btn_counter.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnCount)

        # Button opening the child frame

        btn_new_frame = wx.Button(test_panel, label = "Open new frame",
                                    pos=(100,100))

        btn_new_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnNewFrame)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

        # Frame displaying
        self.Show()

    def OnClose(self, event):

        self.Destroy(True)

    # Method used to close the parent frame
    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()
        print("closed")


    # Method used to count number of click
    def OnCount(self, event):
        self.click +=1
        print(self.click)

    # Method calling wx_Practicing_child.py to open a child frame
    def OnNewFrame(self, event):
        if self.child.OpenButtonFlag == 0 :
            self.child = wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child()
            self.child.label = "child"
            print("Flag before",self.child.OpenButtonFlag)
            self.child.Show()
            print("new Frame opened")
            self.child.OpenButtonFlag = 1
        else :
            print("Frame already launched, close the previous one and retry")
        print("Flag after", self.child.OpenButtonFlag)


"""Class of the panel"""

class PanelMainWindow(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

test = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow()

test.MainLoop()
```

and wx_Practicing_child.py

```
import wx
import time


"""Classe définissant une frame (i.e la zone globale parente). Elle permet
de faire exister le panel et ses attributs."""

class MainWindow_child(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test", wx.DefaultPosition,
        (1000,850), wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, wx.FrameNameStr)

        self.OpenButtonFlag = 0
        self.label = "Child"

        # Sizers
        sizer_hori = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_verti = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Init of the panel

        test_panel_child = PanelMainWindow_child(self)
        test_panel_child.SetSizer(sizer_verti)

        # Buttons declaration
        # Button to quit the frame
        btn_quit = wx.Button(test_panel_child, label ="Quit")
        btn_quit.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnQuit)
        sizer_verti.Add(btn_quit)

    # Method used to quit the frame
    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.OpenButtonFlag = 0
        self.Destroy()
        print("child print", self.OpenButtonFlag)



"""Class which defines a panel for the child frame"""

class PanelMainWindow_child(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
```

So my main problem is that when I click on the "Quit" button or the "x" box on the parent frame (wx_practicing.py), the frame is closed, but the program does not shutdown. After few tries, I have noticed that it seems to be caused by the declaration of self.child in MainWindow.

However, I need this declaration to allow MainWindow to open a MainWindow_child.
I have tried to add a self.child.Close() in my Onquit() method in my MainWindow class but it has been unsuccessful.

After some research, I have seen that I could maybe use CloseEvent handler, but I did not really understand its purpose and how it works.

I hope I have been clear enough.

NOTE: Both programs are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow

The problem with your code is that you are creating two MainWindow_child instances. You can see this by adding `print(self.child)` below each line like `self.child = wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child()` in file wx_Practicing.py. If you run your code now and creates a child frame you get something like:

```
<wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child object at 0x102e078b8>
<wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child object at 0x1073373a8>
Flag before 0
new Frame opened
Flag after 1
```

The first two lines above mean that you have two instances of MainWindow_child and the pointer `self.child` points only to one of them. So when you use `self.child.Destroy()` or close the child frame in the normal way (red X button) you are destroying only one instance. The other instance keep living forever because you never show it, so you cannot press the close button to destroy it or use `self.child.Destroy()` because self.child is pointing to a different object. The living forever child frame is the reason why your program never closes.

For more clarity, if you change the `OnQuit()` and `OnClose()` methods in wx_Practicing.py to:

```
def OnClose(self, event):
    try:
        self.child.Destroy()
    except Exception:
        pass
    self.Destroy()

# Method used to close the parent frame
def OnQuit(self, event):
    try:
        self.child.Destroy()
    except Exception:
        pass
    self.Destroy()
    print("closed")
```

the program will close if you do not press the `Open new frame` button because `self.child` points to the only instance of the child frame. Once you press the button then you have two instance, one of them not shown and without a pointer and the program does not close anymore.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine now. But I still have some misunderstanding stuff. Does "Exception" is a specific type of exception handled by Python, or is it a by-default one for object ? You also mentionned a problem about informations sharing between the parent and the child under @Rolf post. Does it have a connection with the fact that I create 2 references of my child frame, so the parent could be lost with which one it has to share datas ?

Comment: 1- except Exception it to handle any error that may arise when trying to destroy a child frame that does not exist anymore. 2- Yes if you do not keep track of which child frame is the pointer self.child pointing to you may send part of the information to one instance and another part to the second, third child frame. It is better to control this to avoid weird behavior. Why exactly you say: I need this declaration to allow MainWindow to open a MainWindow_child?

Comment: @ClemZer `Exception` in this case is any exception i.e. if there is any issue just `pass` don't worry about it.

Comment: I have made previous topic because I faced issues to open one and only one child frame (the help was given by you by the way, thanks again). If I remove self.child = wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child(self), it will cause an error in my program due to the lack of reference to self.child for my OpenNewFrame() method. Or maybe I created this method in the wrong way and I need to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Call the child window with a `parent` i.e.

```
self.child = wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child(self)
```

Declare the parent in the child i.e.

```
class MainWindow_child(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Test", wx.DefaultPosition,
        (1000,850), wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, wx.FrameNameStr)
```

Now the child will be destroyed when the parent is destroyed and the program will exit cleanly.

I assume that `test_panel_child = PanelMainWindow_child(self)` is some sort of editing error, which should really read `test_panel_child = wx.Panel(self)`.
Use `self.Destroy()` **not** `self.Destroy(True)`

Another way to do this is to **not** perform an initial call to the child frame and move the child open flag into the parent.
To achieve this the child needs to make a note of the parent and ensure that the child open flag is set to false not only on the quit button but also on the window close in the top right-hand corner.

This makes your main program like so:

```
import wx
import time
import wx_Practicing_child
import threading
import os
import sys

"""Class which defines my main frame."""

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test", wx.DefaultPosition,
        (400,350), wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, wx.FrameNameStr)

        # Click counter
        self.click = 0

        # Init of the opening variable which is set to 1 when a child frame is opened
        self.OpenButtonFlag = 0

        # Init of the frame child invoked by the parent frame
        #self.child = wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child(self)
        #self.child.label = "child"
        self.child_open_flag = False

        # Sizers
        sizer_hori = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_verti = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Init of the panel

        test_panel = PanelMainWindow(self)
        test_panel.SetSizer(sizer_verti)

        # Buttons declaration
        # Button to quit the main frame
        btn_quit = wx.Button(test_panel, label ="Quit")
        btn_quit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        sizer_verti.Add(btn_quit)

        # Button counting number of time you trigger it

        btn_counter = wx.Button(test_panel, label="Click counter")
        sizer_verti.Add(btn_counter)
        btn_counter.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnCount)

        # Button opening the child frame

        btn_new_frame = wx.Button(test_panel, label = "Open new frame",
                                    pos=(100,100))

        btn_new_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnNewFrame)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

        # Frame displaying
        self.Show()

    def OnClose(self, event):

        self.Destroy()

    # Method used to close the parent frame
    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()
        print("closed")

    # Method used to count number of click
    def OnCount(self, event):
        self.click +=1
        print(self.click)

    # Method calling wx_Practicing_child.py to open a child frame
    def OnNewFrame(self, event):
        if self.child_open_flag:
                wx.MessageBox("Frame already launched, close the previous one and retry",'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        else:
            self.child = wx_Practicing_child.MainWindow_child(self)
            self.child.label = "child"
            self.child.Show()
            self.child_open_flag = True

"""Class of the panel"""

class PanelMainWindow(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

test = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow()

test.MainLoop()
```

**and your child program**

```
import wx
import time

"""Classe définissant une frame (i.e la zone globale parente). Elle permet
de faire exister le panel et ses attributs."""

class MainWindow_child(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Test", wx.DefaultPosition,
        (200,250), wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, wx.FrameNameStr)
        # make parent accessible
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = "Child"

        # Sizers
        sizer_hori = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_verti = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Init of the panel

        test_panel_child = wx.Panel(self)
        test_panel_child.SetSizer(sizer_verti)

        # Buttons declaration
        # Button to quit the frame
        btn_quit = wx.Button(test_panel_child, label ="Quit")
        btn_quit.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnQuit)
        #Reset the open flag if the child is closed not using the button
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        sizer_verti.Add(btn_quit)

    # Method used to quit the frame
    def OnQuit(self, event):
        # clear the child open flag in the parent
        self.parent.child_open_flag = False
        self.Destroy()
```

[image]

Comment: This will take care of destroying all child frames but it does not solve the problem of creating multiple instances of child frame for no reason. This could be a problem if the OP needs to pass info to and from the child frame.

Comment: Thanks, I did not even think about the fact I had to create a place to add a link to the child in the child constructor.

Comment: I've added a more complete answer, if it helps.

Comment: @kbr85 Point taken. I didn't really see the purpose behind creating it twice, other than to set the open flag, which can be defined and held in the main program.

Comment: @ClemZer I changed `OnNewFrame` to allow for the fact that `self.child` had not been previously called. But if you're happy with your method that's fine. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I've noticed it. Also, thanks for the flag tips, I thought it was not possible to handle it only in the main program. In fact it is a very big help for me.
Both of you helped me a lot, thanks a lot.
(PS : To be honest I'm always a bit afraid to post a useless topic).